# Having trouble getting Reference field option limit and Entity reference autofill to work together

Tags: entities

I am working on an inventory system that would take a shipment and autofill the customer name which would then limit the commodity type. I am able to get the autofill and the limit to work separately but I can't them to work together so in one click both modules execute. As of right now, I have it so when you type in the shipment it autofills but then you have to press the customer again in order for the commodity to limit. Any help on getting these two modules to work together will be greatly appreciated.

Also, in the autofill module I have taken out the $overwrite or else the option to limit to commodity type doesn't exist.

[Reference field options](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit)

[Entity reference autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill)